# Any scientific evidence supporting positive effects from video games playing?

Tags: mental-health

*According to the below website, video games are associated with many negative side effects such as*

> - **Social isolation**
> - Practicing violent acts may contribute more to **aggressive behavior**    than passive television watching.
> - **Academic achievement may be negatively related to over-all time spent    playing video games.**

http://www.education.com/reference/article/negative-potential-video-games/

Are there any studies reporting **positive effects of video games on health**?